# Which expression is more gas efficient of the following: "n != 0" or "n > 0"?

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

What is the more gas-efficient expression to check for non-equality? Is it `n != 0`, or `n > 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (Appendix G - Fee Schedule), the gas costs for the relevant opcodes are as follows:

- [EQ](https://www.evm.codes/#14): 3 gas
- [ISZERO](https://www.evm.codes/#15): 3 gas
- [GT](https://www.evm.codes/#11): 3 gas

The first expression (`n != 0`) utilizes both the `EQ` and the `ISZERO` opcodes as follows: `iszero(eq(x, 0))`. While the second expression (`n > 0`) only utilizes the `GT` opcode as follows: `gt(x, 0)`.

Therefore, the expression `n > 0` is more gas-efficient than `n != 0` by 3 gas units.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no difference, at least as long as we're talking about Solidity 0.8.x with optimizer enabled.

While @Ahmed Ihsan Tawfeeq is right that the codegen generates different instructions in these cases, the optimizer is smart enough to reduce both versions to the same code. Let's prove it.

The code below will compile a small code snippet twice, once with `>` and then with `!=`. It tells the compiler to generate the EVM assembly (using the legacy codegen) as well as the Yul code (using the new codegen). Then runs diff to show differences in the output.

```bash
cat <<EOF > test.sol
contract C {
    function f(uint n) public pure returns (bool) {
        if (n > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
EOF

solc test.sol --optimize --asm --ir-optimized --debug-info none --metadata-hash none > gt.out
sed -i 's/>/!=/' test.sol
solc test.sol --optimize --asm --ir-optimized --debug-info none --metadata-hash none > neq.out
diff --report-identical-files gt.out neq.out
```

Diff output:

```
Files gt.out and neq.out are identical
```

This proves that the optimizer removes any differences from the code produced by either codegen.

Now, if you remove `--optimize`, you'll indeed see a difference:

```
82,83c82
<       gt
<       iszero
---
>       eq
330c329
<                 let expr_9 := gt(cleanup_t_uint256(expr_7), convert_t_rational_0_by_1_to_t_uint256(expr_8))
---
>                 let expr_9 := iszero(eq(cleanup_t_uint256(expr_7), convert_t_rational_0_by_1_to_t_uint256(expr_8)))
```

This difference exists only in unoptimized code.